# Devolver secuencia desde la posición n cuando se pulsa un botón

Tags: python, python-3.9

Estoy haciendo una secuencia, y estoy intentando devolverla desde la posición n, cuando se pulsa un botón.

```
#secuencia de leds con boton de secuencia invertida
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Configuración de pines
led_pins = [15, 16, 18, 22]
button_pin = 23

 #Configuración de la Raspberry Pi
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led_pins, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button_pin, GPIO.IN)
sentido = True
```

Realiza la secuencia de encendido/apagado de LED individuales

```
def encender_led(led_pin):      #enciende leds
    GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)

def apagar_led(led_pin):        #apaga leds
    GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

bucle infinito e intentar empezar desde la última posición de la secuencia anterior, si previamente he pulsado el botón

```
while True:
    
    if sentido == True:           #inicia la secuencia normal
        led_pin = inverso       #Intento empezar desde la última posición de la secuencia anterior
        for led_pin in led_pins:  #enciende y apaga los LED uno a uno
            encender_led(led_pin)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            apagar_led(led_pin)
```

al pulsar el botón se guarda la última posición de la secuencia y cambia el estado de la variable bool " sentido ".

```
            if GPIO.input(button_pin) == True:  #si el botón es presionado
                inverso = led_pin    #guarda la última posición de la secuencia
                sentido = False #cambia el estado de la variable bool "sentido"
                time.sleep(0.2)
```

La secuencia se ejecuta en sentido contrario

```
    if sentido == False:    #se ejecuta mediante el cambio de estado de " sentido".
```

aquí intento que realice el retorno desde la última posición de la secuencia anterior

```
        led_pin = inverso.    #Intento empezar en la última posición de la secuencia anterior
        for led_pin in reversed(led_pins):  #invierto la secuencia 
            encender_led(led_pin)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            apagar_led(led_pin)
```

Si vuelvo a pulsar el botón, guardo la última posición y la variable bool "sentido" cambia de estado

```
            if GPIO.input(button_pin) == True:
                inverso = led_pin #Guardo la última posición de la secuencia
                sentido = True #cambio de estado la variable bool "sentido", para volver a la secuencia anterior
                time.sleep(0.2) #rebote del botón
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he encendido correctamente, la idea es que los led se enciendan y apaguen secuencialmente de forma infinita y el botón simplemente cambia la dirección. Una forma simple de iterar indefiniamente sobre una lista es usar indizado junto a la operación modulo:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c"]

indice = 0
while True:
    print(lista[indice])
    indice = (indice + 1) % len(lista)
```

para iterar en orden inverso basta con restar 1 en vez de sumarlo:

```
indice = (indice - 1) % len(lista)
```

Si usas una variable que almacene este 1/-1 puedes usarla para cambiar el sentido.

```
sentido = 1
pin_index = 0
len_pins = len(led_pins)

while True:
    led_pin = led_pins[pin_index]

    encender_led(led_pin)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    apagar_led(led_pin)

    pin_index = (pin_index + sentido) % len_pins
    
    if GPIO.input(button_pin):
        sentido *= -1 
        time.sleep(0.2)
```